# How to access src folder libraries by service worker in Next.js PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm facing a design challenge regarding how to reuse libraries by a service worker in a Next.js progressive web app (PWA)

The folder structure of my PWA looks like this:
[image]

About the structure:

- Within the `/public` folder there's a service worker called `sw.js`
- The `/src/lib` folder contains a `IDBManager.js` for IndexedDB opertions
- The `/src/api` folder contains a `IDB.js` as an API endpoint to execute IndexedDB operations. The `IDB.js` imports the `IDBManager.js`.

The situation is that the `sw.js` service worker can just access files in its scope that means in the same directory and subfolders. In order to execute IndexedDB opertions by the service worker I would have to duplicate code of `IDBManager.js` to a file in the public folder.

To prevent duplicate code my **idea** is to provide the service worker the API endpoint (`IDB.js`) which can be reached by the service worker via a `fetch()` call.

The service worker's `fetch()` call works but `IDB.js` gives an error when calling `openDB()` to open the IndexedDB. The error message is:
[image]

This error doesn't appear when `openDB()` is not called by the service worker. Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this error is or how to design a PWA with code reuse by the service worker?